# Linux screenshots, how to take them like a mac

Tags: linux, macos, screenshot, opensuse-11.2

I run opensuse 11.2 KDE 4.3.5.

I do not have a mac, but I've used one and really like the one feature of the screenshots. Specifically, Command+Shift+3 which saves the screenshot to the desktop without having to open a program or anything like that.

Is there any way to do this in KDE? Ksnapshot is nice, but I'd like not to have to click the button every time.

I've tried the command line Import and it always gives me some *X server not configured* error or something, so that's not an option.

Comment: (Your typo 'not confectioned' (instead of 'not configured,' I assume) made me smile.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you said you had a problem with ImageMagick, but I think you should ask another question about why import is not working for you.

And then when you have that working something like this could help.... (maybe)

---

Well I found this page on [how to take a screenshot on ubuntu linux](http://tips.webdesign10.com/how-to-take-a-screenshot-on-ubuntu-linux), 
and there I picked the ImageMagick way and wrapped that in a little script.
(or try scrot).

Save this in ~/bin/take_screenshot.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

time=`date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S`
import -window root ~/screenshot_$time.png
#scrot ~/screenshot_$time.png
```

Then make the script executable

```
chmod 755 bin/take_screenshot.sh
```

Then you add a keyboard shortcut that execute this script
(well first you should try to run it from the terminal and make sure it is working...).

And now when you press that Command+Shift+3 a screenshot will be saved in your home dir with a unique name, something like screenshot_20100318_074618.png.

Comment: Amazing. Wonderful. Perfection. 
Note, i did install Scrot in yast, so I don't know if that makes it work or not, but it works with it.

Comment: Also, I changed it to this:
import -window root ~/Desktop/screenshot_$time.png Just FYI for anyone else who might use this.

Comment: That link above is not working anymore. That's the bad part of not writing the full stuff here :(

Answer (score 6):

I use [Shutter](http://shutter-project.org/) for all my Linux screenshooting needs. You can set it to save screenshots on your desktop, and you can easily set keyboard shortcuts for it, so it should handle your particular question, as well as make most screenshot-related tasks much easier.

Comment: +1 for pointing me to Shutter, It is an awesome program.

Answer (score 3):

On Linux:

1) Applications —> Accessories —> Take Screenshot.

2) Print Screen" (PrtSc) button on your keyboard.

I think there is no Mac equivalent for  applekey + shift + 4 or windows snipping tool

Thank you

Comment: I know how to do all that, its easy, but I'm looking for this extra feature of being able to save to desktop without hitting a save button or pasting it.

Answer (score 1):

Binded custom keyboard shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> with script that will provide crosshair pointer similar as OSX <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd>:

```
#!/bin/bash
savepath=$HOME/Desktop/screenshots
import $savepath/`date +"%H:%M:%S_%m-%d-%y_"`screenshot.jpg
```

Comment: This works like a charm!!

Answer (score 0):

To add the hotkey for it, open personal settings (in opensuse KDE at least) go to input actions, Edit, new>global shortcut>command/url then
add your trigger hotkey, and then put the full path in the action
mine was /home/michael/bin/screenshot.sh ( i had it chmoded at 777)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the print screen "PrtSc" key on your keyboard, in KDE (and Gnome, for that matter). Alternatively, Application Launcher Menu >> Graphics >> KSnapshot. This should give you a pretty GUI with a number of options.

Comment: Yes, I've said i Know how to take a screenshot, I'm not a noob. But I was looking for a way to do it without open a program or having to hit anything beyond a set of hotkeys. Ksnapshot you hit Printscreen and then you have to hit save each time. The answer i marked as best, allows you to take multiple sceenshots in quick succession without hitting anything more than the hotkey.